# Maximum input for the second input?

Tags: jquery, html, input, max

I would like to know, how to limit the input based on the first input. Let say that in the first input, `10` was entered. Then, the second input should not be allowed to exceed 10.

```
<input type="number" id="a1" value=""/>
<input type="number" id="a2" value="" max=""/>
```

In the first time, i thought about jQuery to set the `max` attribute. but, I cannot set `max`, but only the input value. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#a1').on('change input', function(){
    $('#a2').attr('max', this.value);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e82q4/)

---

Place two events `change input` change input occurs when you click the arrows up/down of `input[type="number"]` and input occurs when you press any key or paste some value init.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, those JQ works well. And also C-link code is works well. the different is this one can has equal value.

Comment: You should also set the #a2's value if it's bigger than #a1 newer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$('#a1').on('change blur',function(){
   $('#a2').prop('max',this.value++);
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S37N2/)

Comment: What if I change the #a1 value after a while?

Comment: what if a1 value is less

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen for changes applied to #a1 and update the max property of #a2. You can use jQuery, but Vanilla JS will do just fine(and faster).

There is one problem. If you have #a1's value 10, and #a2's value is 9, you will have to decide what to do with the #a2's value if you change #a1 to something smaller, like 5.

Comment: yeah that's a problem too. the simple one maybe double checking, when it is submit, then i need to check if it bigger or not. if bigger then cancel the submit. But, I think it can be done by simple way with jquery, but i am confused haha

Comment: You just need a change listener, the rest will come, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following :

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#a2").attr('maxlength',$("#a1").attr("maxlength"));
});
```

and then listen to changed dom value of a1 div doing something like [this](http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery

```
$('#a1').on('change', function(){
    var two = $('#a2');
    two.attr('max',$(this).val());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zmma/)

**Note:** Works if you try to increment using the `up-down arrow` inside the input (html 5 property)

Answer (score 0):

you can on keyup event of second input .

```
$('#a2').on('keyup', function(){
    var v2=parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    var v1 =parseInt($('#a1').val()) || 0;
    if(v2 > v1){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/bwJYS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to change event of '#a1' and onchange event handler change max attribute of #a2.

```
$( "#a1" ).change(function() {
  $('#a2').attr('max',$(this).val());
});
```